# How to wait till list of file starting with some character is created

Tags: java

```
    File dir = new File(dirName);
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    dir.listFiles(new FileFilter()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file)
        {
            if (!file.isFile()){
                return false;
            }

            String name = file.getName();

            if (!StringUtils.startsWith(name, startsWith)){
                return false;
            }

            if (!StringUtils.endsWith(name, ensWith)){
                return false;
            }

            files.add(file);
            s_logs.log(Level.INFO, "File that startswith " + startsWith + " found ");
            return true;

        }
    });
```

This code is used for getting all file starting with character but i want to wait till file is created.
Could you please suggest a way?

Comment: But you still need to create the files. This only create a `List` of `File`, these instances are not creating the file on the storage system automaticly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something called as a `WatchService` that is available in the new `java.nio.file` package in Java.

You can observe a directory for any file creation using this. You can also check the directory recursively if needed. Oracle also has put up a code sample that you can use to get started.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java

You will need to modify the `processEvents()` method in the above sample and check if the `child` object begins with the character that you are trying to look for.

Hope this helps you get started!